# How to get *chars and return a non-integer?

Tags: c, pointers, char, double, decimal

I'm trying to get characters from the keyboard and return a double so that I can write input "number.number" and in return get the double number.number

As of now I have the following code but my program stops working when executed.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double number(char *ch) {
    double s=1, d=0, x=0;
    char *ch2= 0;

    switch (*ch) {
        case '+':  *ch = getchar(); break;
        case '-':  *ch = getchar(); s = -1; break;
    }
    while ( ('0' <= *ch) && (*ch <= '9') ) {
        d = 10*d + (*ch - '0');
        *ch = getchar();
    }
    if(*ch == '.'){
        *ch2 = getchar();
        while ( ('0'<=*ch2) && (*ch2<='9') ) {
            x = (*ch2 - '0') / 10;
            d = x + d;
        }
    }
    return (s * d);
}   

int main(void) {
    double d;
    char ch;

    ch = getchar();
    d = number(&ch);
    printf("%f",d);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and it's very possible that there are obvious errors in my code as I'm a bloody beginner.

Comment: @Lucky This looks like C, not C++.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `strtod`?

Comment: Please elaborate on "...program stops working when executed". Please read the online help on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Indicate any specific input you gave to the program, what results you saw, and what results you expected.

Comment: It hangs in the while loop where you forget the getchar

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be simpler to use [strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead of writing your own function for this task.

Secondly, your function structure is not meaningful. It does not make sense to read the first character from standard input inside the function `main` and read all subsequent characters from inside another function. You should only use subroutines for specific sub-tasks.

However, these two issues are not the reason for your program crashing. The reason is that all code after reading the `'.'` references `*ch2` instead of `*ch`. In contrast to `ch`, which points to a valid `char`, the pointer `ch2` points to nothing. It is initialized to point to memory address 0. Therefore, your program will crash when you attempt to access memory address 0, because there is nothing there that your program is allowed to access.

There is no reason to have this second pointer `ch2`. If you delete the line in which it is declared and replace all references to it with `ch`, then the crashing issue will be resolved.

However, after fixing this bug, your program will still not work, because it has another bug. It will get stuck in an infinite loop, because your second `while` loop keeps on checking whether the read in character is between '0' and '9' without ever reading in any new characters. Therefore, you must add the line '*ch = getchar();' as you did in your first `while` loop.

After fixing these two bugs, your program will no longer crash or get stuck in an infinite loop. It still will not give the correct result, as your logic for calculating the fractional part is wrong, but I will leave it up to you on how to solve this new problem.

However, what I would like to do is show you is how to structure your program better. As I have already stated, it does not make sense how you have structured your program. Calling `getchar` both from inside main and from inside your subroutine is not meaningful. It would have been better to simply write all your code into the function main() if you cannot find a meaningful way to divide your program into several functions.

If you want to divide your program into a subroutine, I would recommend the following:

```
double read_number()
{
    double s = 1, d = 0, x = 0;
    char c;

    c = getchar();

    switch ( c ) {
    case '+':
        c = getchar();
        break;
    case '-':
        c = getchar();
        s = -1;
        break;
    }

    while ( ('0' <= c) && (c <= '9') ) {
        d = 10 * d + (c - '0');
        c = getchar();
    }

    if ( c == '.' ) {
        c = getchar();
        while ( ('0' <= c) && (c <= '9') ) {
            x = (c - '0') / 10;
            d = x + d;
            c = getchar();
        }
    }

    return(s*d);
}


int main( void )
{
    double d;

    d = read_number();

    printf( "%f", d );

    return 0;
}
```

That way, you no longer have to pass a parameter by pointer (which makes your program unnecessarily complicated).

Please note that this code still contains the bug I mentioned above in which the fractional part is not calculated properly.

As a side note, I would also like to point out that, as a rule, you should not store the result of `getchar` into a `char`, but rather into an `int`, because a `char` is not large enough to store the result if a non-character (such as EOF) is returned from `getchar`. See the [documentation on `getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) for further information. However, this is not the reason why your program is not working.